Train the transformer with PPO
Context
I'm trying to apply reinforcement learning to the transformer.
I have the following tokens: ["<sos>", "<eos>", "roses", "are", "red"].
My goal is to use the transformer-based policy network to generate the tokens ["<sos>", "red", "<eos>"] given the input ["roses", "are"].
The policy network takes the source and target inputs to generate the logits for the next token.
For example, the source input is ["roses", "are"], and the target input is ["<sos>"].
With those inputs, the policy network would generate logtis hopefully corresponding to the "red" token.
I repeat this process in an auto-regressive manner until the "<eos>" token is generated.
For the value network, I use LSTM.
The value network takes source and target inputs just like the transformer.
It concatenates source and target tokens and generates a single value (hidden state) representing the value.
For example, it concatenates the source ["roses", "are"] and target ["<sos>", "red", "<eos>"] to ["roses", "are", "<sos>", "red", "<eos>"] and generate a number.
I train the policy and value networks using PPO and GAE.
Each episode is done when the policy network is finished generating tokens.
I don't calculate the value until the tokens are fully generated.
In other words, I determine rewards only when I have the full tokens.
I have the following reward/penalty rules:

Add -1 score for each mismatching target token length. For example, the desired target token length is 3 (["<sos>", "red", "<eos>"]). If the policy generated 5 tokens, -2 scores will be added to penalize the incorrect generation.
Add +1 score for each correct token with the correct index.
Add +10 scores if the generated tokens are exactly what I expected.

Question
The output settles with the incorrect values during training.
I noticed that the model even generated the perfect output and received a lot of rewards at one point.
However, it changed the behavior incorrectly in the subsequent episodes.
I want to know what I am doing wrong.
Is it just a programming mistake, wrong rewarding rules, or a misunderstanding some theories?
Here is the code I wrote using PyTorch:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from tensordict import TensorDict
from tensordict.nn import TensorDictModule, InteractionType
from torch import optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical
from torch.nn import Embedding
from torchrl.modules import ProbabilisticActor, ValueOperator
from torchrl.objectives import ClipPPOLoss
from torchrl.objectives.value.functional import generalized_advantage_estimate


class OurEmbedding:

    def __init__(self, device):
        self.token_to_index = {
            "<sos>": 0,
            "<eos>": 1,
            "roses": 2,
            "are": 3,
            "red": 4
        }
        self.vocab_size = len(self.token_to_index)
        self.token_vec_dim = 512
        self.device = device
        self.torch_embedding = Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.token_vec_dim, device=self.device)


class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, our_embedding, device):
        super().__init__()
        self.our_embedding = our_embedding
        self.device = device
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim,
            nhead = 8 if self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim % 8 == 0 else 2,
            batch_first = True,
            device=self.device
        )
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim, self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim * 2, device=self.device),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim * 2, self.our_embedding.vocab_size, device=self.device)
        )

    def forward(self, src_token_vecs, target_token_vecs):
        """
        Predict the next token.
        Note that we assume the inputs are not batched.
        :param src_token_vecs: Same meaning as the `nn.Transformer.forward(src, tgt)`.
                               Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :param target_token_vecs: Same meaning as the `nn.Transformer.forward(src, tgt)`.
                                  Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :return: The raw score (logit) for the next token.
                 Shape: (vocab_size).
        """
        # Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        transformer_output = self.transformer(src_token_vecs, target_token_vecs)
        # Shape: (token_vec_dim).
        last_token_vec = transformer_output[-1]
        return self.fc(last_token_vec)

class ValueNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, our_embedding, device):
        super().__init__()
        self.our_embedding = our_embedding
        self.device = device
        hidden_size = self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim * 2
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim,
            hidden_size=hidden_size,
            device=self.device
        )
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size * 2, device=self.device),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, 1, device=self.device)
        )

    def forward(self, src_token_vecs, generated_token_vecs):
        """
        Evaluate the performance of the policy.
        Note that we assume that the inputs are not batched.
        :param src_token_vecs: Same meaning as the `nn.Transformer.forward(src, tgt)`.
                               Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :param generated_token_vecs: Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :return: Value. Shape: (1).
        """
        # Shape: (number_of_combined_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        input_tensor = torch.cat((src_token_vecs, generated_token_vecs), dim=0).to(self.device)
        # The `hidden_state` shape: (1, hidden_size).
        # We assume that LSTM is unidirectional, and the number of layers is 1.
        _, (hidden_state, _) = self.lstm(input_tensor)
        fc_output = self.fc(hidden_state.squeeze(dim=0))
        return self.fc(hidden_state.squeeze(dim=0))


def main():
    seed = 3
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device("cuda")
        torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

    our_embedding = OurEmbedding(device)
    policy_network = PolicyNetwork(our_embedding, device)
    policy_module = TensorDictModule(
        module=policy_network,
        in_keys=["src_token_vecs", "target_token_vecs"],
        out_keys=["logits"]
    )
    actor = ProbabilisticActor(
        module=policy_module,
        in_keys=["logits"],
        # Shape: a scalar representing the next token's index.
        out_keys=["action"],
        distribution_class=Categorical,
        # Make decision in a stochastic manner.
        default_interaction_type=InteractionType.RANDOM,
        return_log_prob=True
    )
    value_network = ValueNetwork(our_embedding, device)
    value_operator = ValueOperator(
        module=value_network,
        in_keys=["src_token_vecs", "target_token_vecs"],
        out_keys=["value"]
    )
    loss_module = ClipPPOLoss(
        actor_network=actor,
        critic_network=value_operator,
    )
    loss_module.set_keys(
        advantage="advantage",
        value_target="value_target",
        value="value",
        action="action",
        sample_log_prob="sample_log_prob"
    )

    # Training

    episode = 0
    max_episode = 1000
    optimizer = optim.Adam(list(policy_network.parameters()) + list(value_network.parameters()))
    while episode < max_episode:
        # We start with 1 because the initial "<sos>" token is already used.
        token_gen_iteration = 1
        done = False
        # It will generate 10 tokens at maximum.
        max_token_gen_iteration = 10
        # Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        src_token_vecs = our_embedding.torch_embedding(torch.LongTensor([2, 3]).to(device))
        # Assuming index=0 corresponds to the "<sos>" token.
        target_token_indexes = [0]
        # It's mutable.
        # Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        target_token_vecs = our_embedding.torch_embedding(torch.LongTensor(target_token_indexes).to(device))
        # It's mutable.
        current_tensor_dict = TensorDict({
            "src_token_vecs": src_token_vecs,
            "target_token_vecs": target_token_vecs
        }, batch_size=[])
        while not done and token_gen_iteration < max_token_gen_iteration:
            current_tensor_dict = TensorDict({
                "src_token_vecs": src_token_vecs,
                "target_token_vecs": target_token_vecs
            }, batch_size=[])
            actor(current_tensor_dict)
            # Shape: a scalar.
            next_token_index = current_tensor_dict["action"]
            target_token_indexes.append(next_token_index.item())
            # The original shape is (token_vec_dim).
            # Since the `target_token_vecs` has the shape of (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim),
            # we need to add one more dimension so that the shape will become (1, token_vec_dim) for the `torch.cat` operation.
            next_token_vec = our_embedding.torch_embedding(next_token_index).unsqueeze(dim=0)
            # Since we want to append the `next_token_vec` as an additional target token, the `torch.cat` dimension is 0.
            # Shape: (number_of_tokens++, same).
            target_token_vecs = torch.cat((target_token_vecs, next_token_vec), dim=0)
            # Assuming index=1 corresponds to the "<eos>" token.
            if next_token_index.item() == 1:
                done = True
            token_gen_iteration += 1
        current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"] = current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"].detach()
        value_operator(current_tensor_dict)
        next_tensor_dict = TensorDict({
            "src_token_vecs": src_token_vecs,
            "target_token_vecs": target_token_vecs
        }, batch_size=[])
        value_operator(next_tensor_dict)

        # Reward/Penalty Rules
        score = 0
        # Penalty for number of tokens being wrong.
        score -= abs(len(target_token_indexes) - 3)
        # Reward for correct indexes.
        if len(target_token_indexes) > 1 and target_token_indexes[1] == 4:
            score += 1
        if len(target_token_indexes) > 2 and target_token_indexes[2] == 1:
            score += 1
        if target_token_indexes == [0, 4, 1]:
            score += 10
        reward = torch.FloatTensor([[score]]).to(device)

        # Note that we need to use batched input and the output will be in batched form.
        advantage, value_target = generalized_advantage_estimate(
            gamma=0.98,
            lmbda=0.95,
            state_value=current_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
            next_state_value=next_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
            reward=reward,
            done=torch.BoolTensor([[1]]).to(device),
            terminated=torch.BoolTensor([[1]]).to(device)
        )
        current_tensor_dict["advantage"] = advantage.squeeze(0)
        current_tensor_dict["value_target"] = value_target.squeeze(0)
        loss_tensor_dict = loss_module(current_tensor_dict)
        loss_critic = loss_tensor_dict["loss_critic"]
        loss_entropy = loss_tensor_dict["loss_entropy"]
        loss_objective = loss_tensor_dict["loss_objective"]
        loss = loss_critic + 0.01 * loss_entropy + loss_objective
        print(f"episode: {episode}, loss_critic: {loss_critic}, loss_objective: {loss_objective}, loss_entropy: {loss_entropy}, score: {score}, target_token_indexes: {target_token_indexes}")
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        episode += 1

main()

And here is the snippet of the console output:
episode: 0, loss_critic: 6.493023872375488, loss_objective: 5.944887638092041, loss_entropy: -0.015881547704339027, score: -7, target_token_indexes: [0, 0, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 3]
episode: 1, loss_critic: 5.89158821105957, loss_objective: 6.10428524017334, loss_entropy: -0.014061596244573593, score: -7, target_token_indexes: [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0]
episode: 2, loss_critic: 1.898949384689331, loss_objective: -2.878739356994629, loss_entropy: -0.012305832467973232, score: -1, target_token_indexes: [0, 1]
episode: 3, loss_critic: 18.447572708129883, loss_objective: -15.853285789489746, loss_entropy: -0.012489358894526958, score: 12, target_token_indexes: [0, 4, 1]
episode: 4, loss_critic: 8.048697471618652, loss_objective: -8.492928504943848, loss_entropy: -0.00397573271766305, score: -1, target_token_indexes: [0, 1]
episode: 5, loss_critic: 9.843278884887695, loss_objective: -10.317561149597168, loss_entropy: -0.0009762179106473923, score: -1, target_token_indexes: [0, 1]
episode: 6, loss_critic: 11.368447303771973, loss_objective: -11.865358352661133, loss_entropy: -0.0002861745888367295, score: -1, target_token_indexes: [0, 1]
episode: 7, loss_critic: 12.705635070800781, loss_objective: -13.205760955810547, loss_entropy: -8.256323781097308e-05, score: -1, target_token_indexes: [0, 1]
episode: 8, loss_critic: 13.895231246948242, loss_objective: -14.395499229431152, loss_entropy: -3.16958139592316e-05, score: -1, target_token_indexes: [0, 1]
episode: 9, loss_critic: 14.960994720458984, loss_objective: -15.460846900939941, loss_entropy: -1.4596819710277487e-05, score: -1, target_token_indexes: [0, 1]

As you can see, it once generated the perfect output ([0, 4, 1]).
However, the model changed its behavior to output [0, 1] and settled to that value.

I found my mistakes and fixed them.
Problem 1: Lack of Exploration
The timing of optimization was bad.
I thought a negative reward would decrease the chance of selecting that action and vice versa.
However, I realized that the absolute magnitude of reward is not what matters.
Instead, the relative difference between rewards leads to desired changes.
Previously, I optimized the agent as soon as it received a reward.
That only encourages the agent to do the same thing.
So, I delayed the optimization in every 100 episodes so that the agent would experience various outcomes and their corresponding rewards.
Problem 2: Discarded Intermediate Actions
Previously, I calculated a reward only with the last action taken by the agent and ignored every previous action.
However, I should've iterated the history of actions and calculated rewards for each action.
Problem 3: Incompetent Value Network
Previously, I used LSTM to calculate the value.
I noticed that using the transformer for the value network significantly improved performance.
To be honest, I'm not sure why the LSTM-based value network didn't perform well.
Solution
Here is the updated code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from tensordict import TensorDict
from tensordict.nn import TensorDictModule, InteractionType
from torch import optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical
from torch.nn import Embedding
from torchrl.modules import ProbabilisticActor, ValueOperator
from torchrl.objectives import ClipPPOLoss
from torchrl.objectives.value.functional import generalized_advantage_estimate


class OurEmbedding:

    def __init__(self, device):
        self.token_to_index = {
            "<sos>": 0,
            "<eos>": 1,
            "roses": 2,
            "are": 3,
            "red": 4
        }
        self.vocab_size = len(self.token_to_index)
        self.token_vec_dim = 8
        self.device = device
        self.torch_embedding = Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.token_vec_dim, device=self.device)


class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, our_embedding, device):
        super().__init__()
        self.our_embedding = our_embedding
        self.device = device
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim,
            nhead = 8 if self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim % 8 == 0 else 2,
            batch_first = True,
            device=self.device
        )
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim, self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim * 2, device=self.device),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim * 2, self.our_embedding.vocab_size, device=self.device)
        )

    def forward(self, src_token_vecs, target_token_vecs):
        """
        Predict the next token.
        Note that we assume the inputs are not batched.
        :param src_token_vecs: Same meaning as the `nn.Transformer.forward(src, tgt)`.
                               Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :param target_token_vecs: Same meaning as the `nn.Transformer.forward(src, tgt)`.
                                  Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :return: The raw score (logit) for the next token.
                 Shape: (vocab_size).
        """
        # Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        transformer_output = self.transformer(src_token_vecs, target_token_vecs)
        # Shape: (token_vec_dim).
        last_token_vec = transformer_output[-1]
        return self.fc(last_token_vec)

class ValueNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, our_embedding, device):
        super().__init__()
        self.our_embedding = our_embedding
        self.device = device
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim,
            nhead=8 if self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim % 8 == 0 else 2,
            batch_first=True,
            device=self.device
        )
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim, self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim * 2, device=self.device),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(self.our_embedding.token_vec_dim * 2, 1, device=self.device)
        )

    def forward(self, src_token_vecs, generated_token_vecs):
        """
        Evaluate the performance of the policy.
        Note that we assume that the inputs are not batched.
        :param src_token_vecs: Same meaning as the `nn.Transformer.forward(src, tgt)`.
                               Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :param generated_token_vecs: Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        :return: Value. Shape: (1).
        """
        # Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        transformer_output = self.transformer(src_token_vecs, generated_token_vecs)
        last_element = transformer_output[-1]
        return self.fc(last_element)


def main():
    torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
    seed = 3
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device("cuda")
        torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

    our_embedding = OurEmbedding(device)
    policy_network = PolicyNetwork(our_embedding, device)
    policy_module = TensorDictModule(
        module=policy_network,
        in_keys=["src_token_vecs", "target_token_vecs"],
        out_keys=["logits"]
    )
    actor = ProbabilisticActor(
        module=policy_module,
        in_keys=["logits"],
        # Shape: a scalar representing the next token's index.
        out_keys=["action"],
        distribution_class=Categorical,
        # Make decision in a stochastic manner.
        default_interaction_type=InteractionType.RANDOM,
        return_log_prob=True
    )
    value_network = ValueNetwork(our_embedding, device)
    value_operator = ValueOperator(
        module=value_network,
        in_keys=["src_token_vecs", "target_token_vecs"],
        out_keys=["value"]
    )
    loss_module = ClipPPOLoss(
        actor_network=actor,
        critic_network=value_operator
    )
    loss_module.set_keys(
        advantage="advantage",
        value_target="value_target",
        value="value",
        action="action",
        sample_log_prob="sample_log_prob"
    )

    # Training

    epoch = 0
    max_epoch = 10000
    optimizer = optim.Adam(loss_module.parameters())
    total_loss = 0
    while epoch < max_epoch:
        # We start with 1 because the initial "<sos>" token is already used.
        token_gen_iteration = 1
        # It will generate 10 tokens at maximum.
        max_token_gen_iteration = 10
        # Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
        src_token_vecs = our_embedding.torch_embedding(torch.LongTensor([2, 3]).to(device))
        # Assuming index=0 corresponds to the "<sos>" token.
        target_token_indexes = [0]
        # It's mutable.
        tensor_dict = TensorDict({}, batch_size=[])
        current_tensor_dict = tensor_dict
        # Take actions until we get the "<eos>" token or reach the maximum token lengths.
        while True:
            # Shape: (number_of_tokens, token_vec_dim).
            target_token_vecs = our_embedding.torch_embedding(torch.LongTensor(target_token_indexes).to(device))
            current_tensor_dict["src_token_vecs"] = src_token_vecs
            current_tensor_dict["target_token_vecs"] = target_token_vecs
            value_operator(current_tensor_dict)
            # Assuming index=1 corresponds to the "<eos>" token.
            if target_token_indexes[-1] == 1 or token_gen_iteration >= max_token_gen_iteration:
                break
            actor(current_tensor_dict)
            current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"] = current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"].detach()
            # Shape: a scalar.
            next_token_index = current_tensor_dict["action"]
            target_token_indexes.append(next_token_index.item())
            current_tensor_dict["next"] = TensorDict({}, batch_size=[])
            current_tensor_dict = current_tensor_dict["next"]
            token_gen_iteration += 1
        # Iterate through the tensor_dict and calculate the advantages.
        current_tensor_dict = tensor_dict
        while "next" in current_tensor_dict:
            done = torch.BoolTensor([[0]]).to(device)
            terminated = torch.BoolTensor([[0]]).to(device)
            if current_tensor_dict["action"].item() == 1:
                done = torch.BoolTensor([[1]]).to(device)
                terminated = torch.BoolTensor([[1]]).to(device)

            # Reward/Penalty Rules
            score = 0
            if len(target_token_indexes) > 1 and target_token_indexes[1] == 4:
                score += 3
            if len(target_token_indexes) == 3:
                score += 5
            if target_token_indexes == [0, 4, 1]:
                score += 10

            next_tensor_dict = current_tensor_dict["next"]
            # Note that we need to use batched input and the output will be in batched form.
            advantage, value_target = generalized_advantage_estimate(
                gamma=0.98,
                lmbda=0.95,
                state_value=current_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
                next_state_value=next_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
                reward=torch.FloatTensor([[score]]).to(device),
                done=done,
                terminated=terminated
            )
            current_tensor_dict["advantage"] = advantage.squeeze(0)
            current_tensor_dict["value_target"] = value_target.squeeze(0)
            current_tensor_dict = current_tensor_dict["next"]
        # Iterate through the tensor_dict and calculate each loss.
        current_tensor_dict = tensor_dict
        while "next" in current_tensor_dict:
            loss_tensor_dict = loss_module(current_tensor_dict)
            loss_critic = loss_tensor_dict["loss_critic"]
            loss_entropy = loss_tensor_dict["loss_entropy"]
            loss_objective = loss_tensor_dict["loss_objective"]
            loss = loss_critic + loss_entropy + loss_objective
            total_loss += loss
            current_tensor_dict = current_tensor_dict["next"]
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            total_loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            total_loss = 0
        print(f"epoch: {epoch}, target_token_indexes: {target_token_indexes}")
        epoch += 1

main()

By the way, it takes a long time to complete the training.
I think I waited around 12 hours.
At least it learned the correct actions at the end :)
